# Append an LI to text/x-jquery-tmpl

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-templates

My Templates:

```
        <script id="tmp_servicebuttons" class="template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
            <li><a class="notification" href="${id}"><img src="${imgsrc}"/></a></li>
        </script>
    <script id="tmp_navigation" class="template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul class="top_bar_notifications">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#home" class="go home">
                            <img src="./resources/img/homebtn.png" alt="Home">
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="back">
                            <img src="./resources/img/backbtn.png" alt="Home">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
...
```

My Home page:

```
    <!-- First Page after splash with main buttons -->
    <script id="tmp_home" class="template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">   
        <section id="${$item.panel_id}" class="home category panel">

            {{tmpl "#tmp_navigation"}}
...
```

How I am trying to append:

```
var data = [{"id": "1", "imgsrc": "./resources/img/servicebtn.png"}];
$("#tmp_servicebuttons").tmpl(data).appendTo(".top_bar_notifications");
```

When I do the following, my navigation template seems to only update on certain sections. I have four sections total. It will update two of the four templates and my home template for some reason is not affected. Anyone know why this would work for one section but not the others? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something, but i'm curious to know why you would need to dynamically change your template structure. Ideally you're template should take care of that logic in the first place. Whatever condition you have to append to the template should be in the template itself.

Comment: I am making a jsonp call to my management console, it returns with the the data I want to then update my jquery tmpl with. I may be approaching this all wrong so if you know a good way I can append a few LIs to the template above I'd love to learn. I don't know much about jQuery tmpl. Thanks!

Comment: I see what you're trying do to. Could you give me an example of what that json looks like when you make your call and just a quick example of what changes you'd like to make to it based on the json. I'm sure we can figure out a way to keep the template static and add the logic in the template rather than changing the structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I was trying to insert html data into my template. That HTML was being interpreted as text. I ended up creating a new template for the LIs and then appended the tmpl to the UL.
Created a template:

```
  <script id="tmp_servicebuttons" class="template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        <li><a class="notification" href="${id}"><img src="${imgsrc}"/></a></li>
  </script>
```

then appended the populated data to the UL

```
var data = JSON.parse(buttons);
$(data).each(function(){
    var data = [{"id": this.id, "imgsrc": this.imgsrc}];
    $("#tmp_servicebuttons").tmpl(data).appendTo(".top_bar_notifications");
});
```